Grab video frame using WMF Framework
I trying to get raw video frame data using Windows Media Framework. Till now my code opens the webcam on my laptop, that can be verified by the webcam LED turns on when my code runs.
But I don't get any data where I supposed to get.
hr = gpVideoReader->ReadSample(streamIndex, 0, nullptr, &flags, nullptr, &gpSample);
hr is S_OK after execution of the API but gpSample is NULL;
Can someone please point me where I'm doing wrong?
Thank you so much.
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <vidcap.h>

#include <ks.h>
#include <ksproxy.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfplay.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfobjects.h>

#include "ddl_log.h"

#define TAG "MAIN"
#define FRAME_WIDTH  680
#define FRAME_HEIGHT 512
#define YUV_FRAME_SIZE (FRAME_WIDTH * FRAME_HEIGHT * 2) // YUV422 format (2 bytes per pixel)

static IMFMediaSource* gpVideoSource = NULL;
static IMFAttributes* gpVideoConfig = NULL;
static IMFActivate** gppVideoDevices = NULL;
static IMFSourceReader* gpVideoReader = NULL;
static UINT32 gVideoDeviceCount = 0;

static IMFMediaType* gpMediaType = nullptr;
static IMFMediaType* gpOutputMediaType = nullptr;
static IMFSample* gpSample = nullptr;
static IMFMediaBuffer* gpBuffer = nullptr;

unsigned char gVideoFrameBuffer[YUV_FRAME_SIZE]; // Global buffer for the frame


static char gFriendlyNameUtf8[256];
static size_t gFriendlyNameUtf8Len = 0;

static WCHAR* gpFriendlyNameW = NULL;
static UINT32 gNameLenW;


class WebcamCapture {
public:
    WebcamCapture() {
        HRESULT exeStatus = NO_ERROR;
       
        CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
        MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

        exeStatus = MFCreateAttributes(&gpVideoConfig, 1);
        DDL_HR_RESULT(exeStatus, "Create attribute store");

        exeStatus = gpVideoConfig->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE,
            MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID);
        DDL_HR_RESULT(exeStatus, "Video capture device SetGUID");

        exeStatus = MFEnumDeviceSources(gpVideoConfig, &gppVideoDevices, &gVideoDeviceCount);
        DDL_HR_RESULT(exeStatus, "Device enumeration");

        exeStatus = gppVideoDevices[0]->GetAllocatedString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME, &gpFriendlyNameW, &gNameLenW);
        if (SUCCEEDED(exeStatus)) {
            wcstombs_s(&gFriendlyNameUtf8Len, gFriendlyNameUtf8, sizeof(gFriendlyNameUtf8), gpFriendlyNameW, gNameLenW);
            DDL_LOGI(TAG, "Friendly name: %s", gFriendlyNameUtf8);
        }

        exeStatus = gppVideoDevices[0]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&gpVideoSource));
        DDL_HR_RESULT(exeStatus, "Activating video device");

        exeStatus = MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(gpVideoSource, gpVideoConfig, &gpVideoReader);
        DDL_HR_RESULT(exeStatus, "Creating video source reader");

    done:
        return;
    }

    ~WebcamCapture() {
        if (gpVideoReader) gpVideoReader->Release();
        if (gpVideoSource) gpVideoSource->Release();
        MFShutdown();
        CoUninitialize();
    }

    HRESULT Initialize() {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void CaptureFrames() {
        HRESULT hr;
        DWORD streamIndex = MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM;
        DWORD flags = 0;
        BYTE* pData = nullptr;
        DWORD maxLength = 0, currentLength = 0;

        if (!gpVideoReader) {
            DDL_LOGE(TAG, "Source reader is not initialized.");
            return;
        }

        // Set the media type for the video stream
        hr = gpVideoReader->GetCurrentMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &gpMediaType);
        if (FAILED(hr) || !gpMediaType) {
            DDL_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to get media type from source reader: 0x%lx", hr);
            return;
        }

        hr = gpVideoReader->SetCurrentMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, NULL, gpMediaType);
        gpMediaType->Release();
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            DDL_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to set media type: 0x%lx", hr);
            return;
        }

        // Read a sample from the video stream
        hr = gpVideoReader->ReadSample(streamIndex, 0, nullptr, &flags, nullptr, &gpSample);
        if (FAILED(hr) || !gpSample) {
            DDL_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to read sample: 0x%lx", hr);
            return;
        }

        hr = gpSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&gpBuffer);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && gpBuffer) {
            hr = gpBuffer->Lock(&pData, &maxLength, &currentLength);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pData) {
                // Copy the data to the global buffer
                memcpy(gVideoFrameBuffer, pData, min(static_cast<size_t>(currentLength), YUV_FRAME_SIZE));
                gpBuffer->Unlock();
            }
            else {
                DDL_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to lock buffer or data pointer is NULL: 0x%lx", hr);
            }
            gpBuffer->Release();
        }
        else {
            DDL_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to convert sample to contiguous buffer: 0x%lx", hr);
        }

        gpSample->Release();

        // Log frame size information
        hr = gpVideoReader->GetCurrentMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &gpOutputMediaType);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && gpOutputMediaType) {
            UINT32 width, height;
            hr = MFGetAttributeSize(gpOutputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, &width, &height);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                DDL_LOGI(TAG, "Video Frame Size: %u x %u", width, height);
            }
            gpOutputMediaType->Release();
        }
        else {
            DDL_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to get output media type or media type pointer is NULL: 0x%lx", hr);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    WebcamCapture capture;
    HRESULT hr = capture.Initialize();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        capture.CaptureFrames();
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize Media Foundation." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


